# Javascript: convert a multidimensional array to object in ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

I try to send a javascript array to php using ajax he's what I did

```
var d = $("#fromDate").val();
var arr = [];
for(var x=0; x<count_select; x++){
       var myArray = new Array();
       myArray['val'] = $("select").eq(x).val();
       myArray['type'] = $("select").eq(x).attr('type');
       myArray['id'] = $("select").eq(x).attr('id');
       arr.push(myArray);
       myArray = new Array();
}
```

The array contains elements as I want in a multidimensional array.

[image: Array screenshot]

But when I send it to php page like this: (Array is not converted yet here's where I want to convert it to send as json)

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "URL_PATH",
     data: {"arrar":arr,"date":d},
     dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

In the network tab i find

```
date    "2017-07-08"
```

and can't find the array so how can I convert this multidimensional  array to an object so I can handle it using php

Comment: in js everything is an object

Comment: pz paste full code here.

Comment: Hey...Are you sure JS supports associative arrays? No it doesn't!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can simplify this using `map()` and by using an object for each item:

```
var arr = $('select').map(function() {
  return {
    val:  this.value,
    id:   this.id,
    type: $(this).attr('type')
  }
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is long  
arr[0][val] "1"
arr[0][id] "72"
arr[0][type] "parent"
arr[1][val] "2"
arr[1][id] "8"
arr[1][type] "sub"
arr[2][val] "0"
arr[2][id] "6"
arr[2][type] "sub"
date "2017-07-08"
How to handle it using php as these are not fixed parameters they might be less or more

Comment: foreach(what?) I get parameters not an object to loop through they are just parameters and don't know their count

Comment: It is an array of arrays in php. If you need count it is `count($_POST['arrar'])` or a loop would be like : `foreach( $_POST['arrar'] as $selectItem)`

Comment: $array = $_POST['arr']; then used foreach to handle the data. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`var myArray = {}` is object not a array .Because  Array not have key value pair in js.

```js
var arr=[];
for(var x=0; x<10; x++){
       var myArray = {};//try with object not a array
       myArray['val'] = 10;
       myArray['type'] = 11;
       myArray['id'] = 12;
       arr.push(myArray);
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = new Array()
array["foo"] = "bar";

console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
// -> []
```

Oops?

The problem here is, that your array is not going to be converted to text properly when its going to be send in the post request. Arrays in JS only expect numbers as indexes, there are no associative arrays in JS. The analogy to associative arrays are objects. where you have a simple key: value store.

What you really want is an `object`

```
var obj = {};
obj["foo"] = "bar";

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
// -> { "foo": "bar" }
```

In Javascript everything is an object, so you *could* do things like:

```
var n = 1;
n.name = "number with property";
```

And you would't get an error, even if that makes no sense ;)

Comment: Well some people voted down, but this is actually the right answer, with explanation